# Mercurial - how do I populate repository descriptions for hgwebdir.cgi?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hgweb

Currently if I specify a description in `hgwebdir.config` it shows up the same for each repository. I want to have a unique name for each repository. Where and how do I set this?

My `hgwebdir.config` looks like this at present:

```
[web]
style = Gitweb
contact = BrianLy
description =  Same description for all. I want a unique description.
allow_archive = gz, zip, bz2

[paths]
/ = /Users/brianly/sandbox/*
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Inside each repository itself is (or can be) a `.hg/hgrc` file.  Put the `[web]` section in there with a `description` entry.  See the [`hgrc` webpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) for all the places that config entries can go.

Comment: The `hgrc` webpage would be this one: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html